# react native - web socket on close event is not called in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, websocket

in our react native app we are using web sockets, sometimes when we have an abnormal closure (websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF)

the event onclose/onerror is not called right away, but after 20-60 minutes later (on ios only). Please note, this issue appears only in background.

this cause our app to not knowing the connection is closed, and it is not initiating new connection

we have tried listening to the network with wireshark but the problem only occurs sometimes and we did not manage catching it for a last 24 hours.

How can we detect such event?

our code:

```
initiateConnection = (url) => {
  this.conn = new WebSocket(url);
  this.conn.onopen = this._handleConnectionOpen;
  this.conn.onerror = this._handleConnectionError;
  this.conn.onclose = this._handleConnectionClose;
  this.conn.onmessage = this._handleMessage;
};

_handleConnectionClose = data => {
  Log.info('WS - connection closed', data.reason);
};

_handleConnectionError = data => {
  Log.info('WS - connection closed', data.reason);
};
```

Comment: The obvious solutions that jump out at me:

1) Try using a different websocket client library since this one can't handle your errors adequately.

2) Fix the syntax error on your server that's causing this. There's probably a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: Im using the react native client, any other library uses the same one. im not sure this is a bug in my code because of the following reasons: 1) it only happens sometimes, for instance i run my applications for a few days and this didn't occur, 2) it only happens for ios devices, not android, and i have the same code for them both.